# Enable UITableView scrolling during a scroll in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`

The table view looks like:

```
private(set) lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .plain)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.rowHeight = 70
    tableView.backgroundColor = .blue
    tableView.bounces = false
    tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return tableView
}()
```

As you see I have disabled the scrolling in the table view because I want it to scroll along with the rest of the views inside the `UIScrollView`. What I want to achieve though, is to enable the scrolling of the tableView when the `UIScrollView` has reached certain offset, therefore I have that in the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 160 {
        self.view.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```

The above works partially. The `UITableView` that just had it's scrolling enabled doesn't scroll, unless I lift my finger off the screen and start scrolling again.

Any ideas how can I get the desired behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

**Important**: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behaviour can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled. [image]

Comment: its documented in apple document. so you need to avoid doing so.