# canEditRowAtIndexPath in a Table that is in a ScrollView doesn't swipe at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have added a tableview inside a scrollview. The tableview returns true for canEditRowAtIndexPath. Issue is, the swipe does not work at once in the tableview. However, didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called at any given time. When tried to swipe a several times it seems to work. What may be causing the issue? Any solutions to overcome this?

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return YES;

}
```

Comment: why you have taken tableView inside scrollview? tableView have already scrolling property because it is subclass of scrollView.

Comment: Maybe he neads scrolling in both directions. The horizontal scroll afforded by the parent scroll view is competing with the horizontal swipe on the rows... Does setting `delaysContentTouches` to `true` on the scroll view help?

Comment: Yes is need scrolling in both directions and as per a the UI design, scrollview and the tableview are needed. Ive already tried enabling and disabling delaysContentTouches. Doesn't seem to have any difference. As I have read, disabling scrollview's scroll worked for someone. But on this case, that didn't make any difference either.

Comment: You should not embed tableview into scrollview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837882/enable-uitableview-scrolling-during-a-scroll-in-uiscrollview/45838105#comment78635143_45838105

Comment: Is there a way to determine where the content touch happened and based on that enable the scrollview or the tableview?